# I want place two buttons in one layout for SAPUI5 mobile application

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5. I'm able to create controls in my SAPUI5 mobile application.But I'm not able to set them in a layout. I'm writing my view as HTML page and adding my controls to that. I have tried placing them in a division but I don't know what is the attribute to specify layout.Please guide about the layouts.

Thanks

```
<template data-controller-name="sample.controllers.index">
<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Page" data-title="Title">
    <div data-sap-ui-aggregation="content">
    <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Layout" data-type="vertical">
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Input"  data-width="20%"
id="Textfield" data-placeholder="User" data-max-length="10"></div><br>
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Input"  data-width="20%" id="Textfield2" data-placeholder="Password" data-type="Password"></div><br>
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.TextArea" data-width="30%" id="textarea" data-placeholder="Text for information..."></div>
    </div>
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Button" id="btn1" data-text="My Button1" data-press="doIt"></div>
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Button" id="btn2" data-text="My Button2" data-press="doIt"></div>
        <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Label" data-text="I'm Label" data-width="100px" data-height="100px" data-background-colour="orange"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my sample code and when i run this on browser it shows me a error message that

> Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/m/Layout.js' from resources/sap/m/Layout.js: 404 - Not Found

here is my index.html

`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
        </script>
        <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

        <script>
                sap.ui.localResources("sample");
                var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"idindex1"});
                var page = sap.ui.view({id:"idindex1", viewName:"sample.views.index", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.HTML});
                app.addPage(page);
                app.placeAt("content");
        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
            <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: I think the problem with bootstrap

Comment: I think so, too. Could you please post your index.html where your bootstrapping is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Layout" data-type="vertical">
```

There is no such a control like `sap.m.Layout`. For layout, you can choose any from the `sap.ui.layout` controls, for example, `sap.ui.layout.Grid`

Comment: Thnq so much Serge.. How should i get access to a part of the page or view. Before i worked on appcelerator there i used to write a view to place my controls. But in SAPUI5 how can arrange them according to my protoype? please help me out. Thnq in advance.

Comment: In case of the sap.m library, the topmost container control should be either App or Shell control. Put there a sap.m.Page where you can place your controls. Why it is needed? sap.m.Page is a good placeholder for applications that use fixed header and footer and scrollable area in between. You can place buttons in the header or in the footer. More complex design with master/detail pages involves use of the splitter control like in the Explored application.